# How to not have moment.js convert dates

Tags: node.js, momentjs, node-oracledb

I have a node.js program, which uses the oracledb package.

It connects to an Oracle database, selects data and stores that data into another Oracle database.

Both databases are configured for UTC for storing date/time values

Here is a code snippet:

```js
let sql = `SELECT a.* FROM some_view a`;
const result = await db1.execute(sql, {}, {
  outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
});
const workOrders= result.rows as WorkOrder[];

...

for (const workOrder of workOrders) {
  await db2.execute(
    `INSERT INTO table(workordernumber, startdate)
     VALUES (:workordernumber, :startdate)`, {
    workordernumber: workOrder.workordernumber,
    startdate: startdate
  },
);
```

The problem is that the date/time values are being converted to my local time zone when stored in the destination system.

I am in EST.  So, 09/07/2022 17:04:08 from the source is stored as 09/07/2022 22:04:08 in the destination.

I have tried using moment, without success, to prevent the conversion on the destination as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table(workordernumber, startdate)
VALUES (:workordernumber, :startdate), {
  workordernumber: workOrder.workordernumber,
  startdate: moment.utc(startdate)
},
```

The values are still converted to my local time zone.

I want to take the UTC values from one database and store them as UTC values in other, without any conversion.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing in the code you're showing performs date conversion or even interpretation, and `moment.js` is nowhere to be seen. Where's the code that actually takes the result of your db query, and "does something with it" (like turning it into strings on a web page, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the following LOGON trigger, in both databases, which will set the session timezone to UTC.  This will prevent the node-oracledb driver from converting the value.  Be sure to create it as Sys so that it is trigger for every user that logs on.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER “SYS”.after_logon_trg
  AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = ''+00:00''';
END;
/
```